# Do pea pod upgrades count a extra plants in PvZ2?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

In Plants vs Zombies 2, to get some stars you must plant less than a given number of plants.

In those levels, do Pea Pod upgrades that go onto existing Pea Pod count as extra plants?

The Encyclopedia seems to indicate this way - it explicitly refers to "multiple plantings" and "repeatedly planted in the same space". Also, I have experienced "losing" the star level when I had zero plants to plant left and I planted a Pea Pod upgrade.

However, I'd like an **official** answer based on some sort of PvZ documentation to confirm my observations and guesses.

Answer (score 5):

Didn't you just answer your own question?

> Also, I have experienced "losing" the star level when I had zero plants to plant left and I planted a Pea Pod upgrade.

So yes, planting a *Pea Pod* anywhere(including existing ones) counts as planting an extra plant.

**EDIT**

From [*Pea Pod* wiki](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Pea_Pod):

> On missions with a limited amount of plants, each head added to the pea pod will count as a new plant.

Comment: Hm. I'm not usually happy with accepting Wiki info as "official", but it beats no info at all. I'll wait to accept for a while though.